# Apollo client not paring UserInputError

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

i am throwing an UserInputError  from the Apollo server, the playground is correctly displaying the error with extension and exceptions, but the the apollo client is not showing the extensions and exceptions.

Comment: How are you attempting to access this data? Please update your question with the code where you're attempting to parse the returned error.

Comment: i'm using promise , and trying to access it in the catch block

Comment: So are you calling `client.mutate` or utilizing the `mutate` function provided by the `useMutation` hook? If you're using the hook, what options are passed to the hook? How are you actually parsing the error returned inside the catch block? Please edit your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: i got it, i stringify the error and found that ,we can access it using error.graphQlErrors[0] , it's weird that it's not written anywhere in the documentation. This sure gave me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stringify the error and found that ,we can access it using error.graphQlErrors[0] , it's weird that it's not written anywhere in the documentation. This sure gave me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer worked for me. Just providing some more details to help future Googlers.

On the apollo-server backend, we are throwing an error:

```
throw new UserInputError("Form Arguments invalid", {
    field: "name",
});
```

On the apollo-client frontend, we are catching that error:

```
try {
    // Perform GraphQL mutation.
} catch (error) {
    // How do we get the "field" extra info?
}
```

As the previous answer says, there is some `graphQlErrors` property that contains extra information. So in this example, I can access `error.graphQlErrors[0].extensions.field` to get the "name" value.